# TypeORM: Set Relation to NULL in update

Tags: sql, typescript, typeorm

I have this Entity

```
@Entity({ name: 'orders' })
export class Order {
 ...

  @ManyToOne(() => BulkOrder, (bulkOrder) => bulkOrder.orders)
  bulkOrder?: BulkOrder
}
```

I'm trying to set the relation to null during an update

```
.createQueryBuilder()
.update(Order)
.set({ status: OrderStatus.OPEN, bulkOrder: undefined }).
where(...).execute()
```

but it's not updating the bulkOrder field, as evidenced in the query that it produces

```
query: UPDATE "orders" SET "status" = $1, "updated_at" = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE ("id" IN ($2, $3) ...
```

How can I set the relation to null? I know I could set it to null and save the entity but I need to use a query builder because I have to make sure to not update unwanted registries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the database standpoint, relation is just a foreign key referencing a primary key. In your case, typeorm under the hood is creating a `bulkOrderId` column in `orders` table, referencing the `id` column from the table corresponding to the `BulkOrder` entity.

In order to remove the relation, you have to set the `bulkOrderId` column to null. One of the proper ways to do this would be:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'orders' })
export class Order {
 ...

  @ManyToOne(() => BulkOrder, (bulkOrder) => bulkOrder.orders)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'bulkOrderId' })
  bulkOrder?: BulkOrder;

  @Column({ name: 'bulkOrderId' })
  bulkOrderId?: string;
}
```

```js
.createQueryBuilder()
.update(Order)
.set({ status: OrderStatus.OPEN, bulkOrderId: null }).
where(...).execute()
```